# Java kernel for Jupyter

Tags: java, jupyter

Is there a java kernel for "Jupyter"? I'm using Mac OS El Capitan.

I tried https://github.com/Bachmann1234/java9_kernel but to no avail.

Comment: you can find a list of available kernels here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages

Comment: Thank you but i don't know how to find my jdk path. Please help

JAVA_9_HOME - like JAVA_HOME but pointing to a java 9 environment

Comment: Trying to make the experimental java9 kernel work is probably not a good idea if you are a beginner. It seems that you have to install an experimental version of java9 and set a couple of environment variables. If you have no clue what I am talking about, you may not want to install this kernel anyway.

Comment: I'm new to Mac OS that's why I can't seem to locate the JAVA_HOME but pointing to a java 9 environment . if you can help me locate that, it wouildn't be a problem.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable. I do not understand your comment. What exactly do you want to locate? The variable? What does that mean?

Comment: it's a shame that Jupyter which emphasizes to be "language i dependent" lacks support for one of the *most* used languages...

Comment: It's not a jupyter kernal but I am aiming to make a workbench for java that allows you to run code snippets and visualize any object as a table or a a chart etc: http://jpad.io

Comment: If you're open to using a different notebook, you can take a look at Beaker (http://beakernotebook.com/) [I am not affiliated with Beaker]. Beaker comes with built-in JavaScript, SQL, Java, Clojure, Groovy, Scala, HTML, TeX, and Markdown support.

Answer (score 27):

There are a number of options, many listed on the official Jupyter [kernel list](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels):

1. The [scijava-jupyter-kernel](https://github.com/scijava/scijava-jupyter-kernel) supports Java for Jupyter

   > scijava-jupyter-kernel aims to be a polyglot Jupyter kernel. It uses the Scijava scripting languages to execute the code in Jupyter client and it's possible to use different languages in the same notebook. Some of the supported languages are Groovy (default), Python, Beanshell, Clojure, **Java**, Javascript, Ruby and Scala. The kernel has been originally created to work with ImageJ. See here for more details. Under the hood scijava-jupyter-kernel uses the Beaker base kernel.
2. [BeakerX](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx) extensions for Jupyter come with [Java cell support](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx/blob/master/doc/contents/javaTutorial.ipynb).

   > BeakerX contains and depends on many projects including: The kernel is originally derived from lappsgrid, but has been rewritten in Java and refactored and expanded. The Java support uses Adrian Witas' org.abstractmeta.toolbox.

**Updated**:

3. [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava), a Jupyter kernel for executing Java code.

   > The kernel executes code via the new JShell tool. Some of the additional commands should be supported in the future via a syntax similar to the ipython magics. The kernel is fully functional. [...] If you are interested in building your own kernel that runs on the JVM check out the related project that this kernel is build on, [jupyter-jvm-basekernel](https://github.com/SpencerPark/jupyter-jvm-basekernel).

You may also be interested in:

4. [Kotlin kernel for IPython/Jupyter](https://github.com/ligee/kotlin-jupyter), a basic kotlin REPL kernel.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a shameless plug, but I think it's important to actually state that at this point *there is no Java kernel for Jupyter*. You can see the list of available kernels [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) in case you think that might have changed when you are reading this.

===== update =====

There is now a new solution that may be relevant here called [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava).

Comment: I offered a newer answer based in part on the updated kernel list -- thanks for linking it.

Comment: Shameless plug for .. *what* ?? Are you on the `zeppelin` team .. or .. ? btw this is *just fine* .. but then you might want to provide a link to the *alternative* implied here.

Answer (score 5):

Try [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava) kernel for Jupyter. This Kernel works only with Java 9 or above. I have using this for some time now with Java 10 on windows. It is working fine, have not noticed any issues so far.

However if you have [scijava-jupyter-kernel](https://github.com/scijava/scijava-jupyter-kernel) , IJava karnel will fail to start. As scijava-jupyter-kernel is dependent on OpenJdk 8. And IJava is compiled with JDK9.

Comment: Hi @Debashish, I have scijava installed in my Jupyter (via Anaconda on windows). Since you have used this, how do you import external JAR files. I keep running into errors. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can see all the available kernels to Jupyter and goes to download page:

https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels

I'm using Linux Fedora 64bit. For Java kernel to Jupyter, I have successfully installed that one without using Anaconda (plz read the readme file carefully):

https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava

To install (Linux command):

```
$ chmod u+x gradlew && ./gradlew installKernel
```

Alternatively, you can try this one:

https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/releases/download/v1.2.0/ijava-1.2.0.zip

and install just with the command-line (in Linux):

```
$ python3 install.py
```

Hope it help you.